# Failed to get Cassandra DataSource cause Spring application context wasn't injected

Tags: xml, cassandra, datasource, ignite

I am running an application written in Scala that is using Spark, Ignite, and persisting from writeThrough cache to Cassandra. From the Ignite base concepts code you are supposed to set the CacheStoreFactory as so:

```
<property name="cacheStoreFactory">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStoreFactory">
        <!-- Datasource configuration bean which is responsible for Cassandra connection details -->
        <property name="dataSourceBean" value="cassandraDataSource"/>
        <!-- Persistent settings bean which is responsible for the details of how objects will be persisted to Cassandra -->
        <property name="persistenceSettingsBean" value="cache1_persistence_settings"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Yet, when I run the application I get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Failed to get Cassandra DataSource cause Spring application context wasn't injected into CassandraCacheStoreFactory

All of the Ignite.xml, connection-settings.xml and cassandra-store.xml are all written the same way as the examples explain on apacheignite Cassandra integration page. Is there something that is missing form the xml doc that specifies the Spring application context for Cassandra DataSource?

Comment: How do you start your Ignite node? Does it have Spring application context supplied?

Comment: @alamar I am calling Ignite from Scala/Spark via: 
`val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(sparkContext, config.igniteConfig, true)
      val ignite = igniteContext.ignite()`